# Is buying a SSD for Ubuntu a good deal?

Tags: laptop, ssd, ubuntu

I want to buy an external drive to run SSD, without touching my Windows HDD. However, this is a little investment so I am wondering if you can answer my few questions. Here are my laptop specs:

- Intel Core i3
- 6GB RAM
- 1 To HDD (Windows 10)
- No graphic card

Honestly, it runs very slowly, 5-10 minutes to startup, ~1 minute to start Microsoft Word. This is not the best laptop but this is not the question here. The questions are:

1. Is a HDD sufficient or it will run slowly as on Windows.
2. Can all external SSD run Ubuntu, or I have to buy one in particular
3. I am sure 256 GB is sufficient but are you sure it is? I would use Ubuntu time to time, for programming, and I won’t store any personnal data or whatever except code.

I have already tried Dual Boot and it was good but I want another drive for Ubuntu now (don’t try to change my mind)

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend you to go with 256GB SSD and install Windows/Ubuntu on it, Performance will increase a lot. I regularly upgrade older system with ssd and use HDD as storage. Go for it.

You could buy an internal 2.5" SSD, then use it in the desktop. Later you could buy an enclosure and put the internal 2.5" SSD into the enclosure to use it as an external drive.

You could use the external drive on multiple computers, even boot from it if the system supports USB boot. You would need to make sure all systems support uefi or legacy (mbr) and format the external to the partition standard you choose on the systems.

This question is about how to [install Ubuntu on an external drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive).

Comment: Buy Internal 2.5" SSD now for desktop, In case you decided to discard  your desktop you can remove SSD put it in an enclosure and use it as external drive.

Comment: yeah I think I’ll do that. But I have one last question then. If I use it as external (still Ubuntu on it), can I use it on multiple laptops/PC?

Comment: not recommended, most of the time it wont work, some links are there for installation. again it is complicated

Comment: mmh... I wanted an external SSD for that... Are you sure there is no way?

Comment: see this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/446682/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-portable-external-hard-drive

Comment: as I understood, this is possible if my laptop/computer can boot from USB (and it can), so it would be possible in my case?

Comment: If both support usb boot (check both supports uefi or legacy(mbr) and have same on both then it is yes

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! You really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

*Is buying a SSD to run Ubuntu a good deal?* It is an excellent idea; I have six Ubuntu PCs and all were upgraded from HDD to SSD with no problem at all, and Ubuntu's performance is much better with the SSD.

If an SSD will work in Windows without any special Windows driver 
on that machine, it will work in Ubuntu. 50 GB would be adequate.

To resolve the low performance issue, I would also review my motherboard manual to see if mixing the memory sizes is likely to cause a problem, for 6 GB means you have a 4 GB and a 2 GB memory module. Since they are different, perhaps their specs are also different, which can also limit performance.